# Orchard s3slider

Tags: orchardcms

Does Orchard CMS have something similar to the [s3Slider](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/)? I have had a look about but can't find anything quite like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard may/may not have something like that, but you can still use s3slider within your Orchard project as it is only jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few. FeaturedItemSlider is one that can be found in the Orchard Gallery. I also created one myself called "ContentSlider", which can be found on codeplex.com.